# Adding option selector in HTML5, CSS, JavaScript similar to option setting in mobile apps

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile, drop-down-menu

I am wondering if it is possible to add a gear image to HTML5, where similar to mobile apps when clicked shows a list of options that user can select. Can this be done using only HTML5, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: You can add an `img` of a gear, and make a menu show/hide with JS when the user clicks on it. So the answer is yes.

Comment: you could even use a icon font. Yes is your answer.... You can close the question now please.

Comment: @Pimskie thanks for the answer. Can you please direct me to an example as I am beginner in html, css, JavaScript? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Search for something like "JS toggle element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question: Yes. It's possible.

You can achieve this by manipulating the CSS with some basic JavaScript.
For example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img id="options-cog" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/token/128/Gear.png" onclick='toggleOptions()'>
        <div id='options-wrapper' style='display:none'> 
            -- A FORM ELEMENT WITH OPTIONS -- 
        </div>
        <script>
            function toggleOptions(){
                var elem = document.getElementById('options-wrapper');
                if(elem.style.display == 'none'){
                    elem.style.display = "block";
                }else{
                    elem.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that this would be easier and better looking using jQuery animations functions.